# I am creating a generic data reader function for get data from database but i am facing a issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a generic data reader function for get data from database but i am facing a issue. "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyBooks.Data.Model.Book"

Kindly Help me

```
 public List<T> GetDataMethod<T>(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.Connection = getcon();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<T> records = new List<T>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            object[] tempRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                tempRow[i] = reader[i];
            }
            //Error showing > can not convert from object[] to T
            records.Add(tempRow);
        }
        return records;
    }
```

Comment: Your data is string , your Book is a object has many properties. How could you use "records.Add(data)" ?

Comment: @QingGuo thanks for your replay. Can u modify my code ?.

Comment: Your sample is lacking things like parameters, using blocks etc. And after all, why don't you simply use Linq To Sql? Are you trying to reinvent it?

Comment: I know i can use linq to sql but i want to learn. I updated my code but i am stucked. here is the error 'Error showing > can not convert from object[] to T'

Comment: @M.Rizwan  see YungDeiza's  updated answer. It is work .

Answer (score 1):

tempRow is a DataRow. And T is of type MyBooks.Data.Model.Book.
What you want to do is map the values to the properties of Book.
E.g. if Book has a property of "Title" and you know, that the title is in the DataRow at index 0:

```
var newBook = new Book();
newBook.Title = tempRow[0];
records.Add(newBook);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type. You'll need to return a list of objects then create code to map between the list of objects to the type you need.

```
public List<object[]> GetDataMethod(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.Connection = getcon();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<object[]> records = new List<object[]>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            object[] tempRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                tempRow[i] = reader[i];
            }
            //Error showing > can not convert from object[] to T
            records.Add(tempRow);
        }
        return records;
    }
```

Comment: I updated my code but stuck at error again "Error showing > can not convert from object[] to T"

u can check my latest code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is what all ORMs do. they need a specific mapper for each type that would be provided by the reflection, annotation, or anything else. Bytheway you could register your own mappers and use them inside your method.

```
namespace Models {
    public record Book(int Id, string Name);
}
```

if you have model for Book.
and you need an interface for all your mappers like this :

```
namespace Mappers {
    public interface IMappers<T> {
        Task<T> MapAsync(object[] fieldsData);
    }
}
```

and the book mapper :

```
using Models;

namespace Mappers {
    public class BookMapper : IMappers<Book>
    {
        public Task<Book> MapAsync(object[] fieldsData)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => new Book( Convert.ToInt32( fieldsData[0]), fieldsData[1].ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

also, you need somewhere to register your mappers to DI :

```
using Mappers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Models;

namespace MiniOrm {
    public static class DependencyRegistration
    {
        public static IServiceCollection RegisterMappers(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IMappers<Book>,BookMapper>();
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

now you would be able to change your method like this :

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Mappers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MiniOrm {
    public class CommandExecuter {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public CommandExecuter(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public List<T> GetDataMethod<T>(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            cmd.Connection = getcon();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<T> records = new List<T>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object[] tempRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    tempRow[i] = reader[i];
                }
            
                var mapper = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMappers<T>>();
                if(mapper == null)
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"No mapper found for type {typeof(T)}");
                records.Add(mapper.MapAsync(tempRow).Result);
            }
            return records;
        }
    }
}
```